# How can I control a RadioGroup from material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-group

I have a React (typescript) app where I want to show a radio group but cut into two columns like so:
[image]

To do so, I use two RadioGroup from `@material-ui/core` that I wish to completely control so the user cannot select an option in each group. My problem is that the RadioGroups don't care about the `value` I give them, they seem to be working in uncontrolled mode. I can even see that the value is OK in their props, in the React DevTools.

Here is how I did it:

```
<div>Organizational attributes</div>
<div>
  <RadioGroup
    value={selectedPivotAttribute && selectedPivotAttribute.id.toString()}
    onChange={selectPivotAttribute}
  >
  {props.attributes.filter(attribute => attribute.isHierarchical).map(attribute => (
    <FormControlLabel
      label={attribute.name}
      key={attribute.id}
      value={attribute.id.toString()}
      control={<Radio/>}
    />
  ))}
  </RadioGroup>
</div>

<div>Secondary attributes</div>
<div>
  <RadioGroup
    value={selectedPivotAttribute && selectedPivotAttribute.id.toString()}
    onChange={selectPivotAttribute}
  >
  {props.attributes.filter(attribute => !attribute.isHierarchical).map(attribute => (
    <FormControlLabel
      label={attribute.name}
      key={attribute.id}
      value={attribute.id.toString()}
      control={<Radio/>}
    />
  ))}
  </RadioGroup>

</div>
```

The two RadioGroups are correctly rendered and functional, they also trigger the `onChange` handler, but they don't care about the value I give them, they just live their own life and thus they are not mutually exclusive.

I am trying to reproduce in a codesandbox but I can't even get one RadioGroup to work at all in there. Here it is anyway: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cloud-yixdd. I can't think of anything simpler than that while remaining relevant to the case.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Alessio's answer I managed to reproduce my situation in a code sandbox available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-napier-huo9b.

In the sandbox, line 47, I set the default value for the state to be an empty string. If you remove that to set it to `undefined`, it will not work.

So the real problem is that when you don't provide a `value` to `RadioGroup` (or if you provide `undefined`), the component will be uncontrolled. Simple as that. To avoid that, I just needed to provide an empty string rather than `undefined` when no selection is intended.

Answer (score 3):

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cloud-hyq90

That's how i manage to make it works

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import {
  RadioGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Radio,
  FormLabel
} from "@material-ui/core";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    value: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    value: "How"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    value: "are"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    value: "you"
  }
];

const data2 = [
  {
    id: "1",
    value: "fine"
  },
  { id: "2", value: "ty" }
];

function App() {
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState({
    value: "1",
    value2: "1"
  });

  const updateSelection = (event, value) => {
    event.persist();
    const name = event.target.name;
    setSelection({ ...selection, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Howdy</FormLabel>
      Value1: {selection.value}, Value2: {selection.value2}
      <RadioGroup
        name="value"
        value={selection.value}
        onChange={updateSelection}
      >
        {data.map(datum => (
          <FormControlLabel
            label={datum.value}
            key={datum.id}
            value={datum.id}
            control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
      <RadioGroup
        name="value2"
        value={selection.value2}
        onChange={updateSelection}
      >
        {data2.map(datum => (
          <FormControlLabel
            label={datum.value}
            key={datum.id}
            value={datum.id}
            control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          />
        ))}
      </RadioGroup>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thank you! I adapted your code to successfully reproduce my situation. I have found the problem and will write an answer for it. Thanks for your help!